# Mobile Web App layout using CSS Grid - how to make rows flex?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a Web App that will replace a native Android App - so it can run on iOS/Mac/Windows/Ubuntu!

I started out with Flexbox - but there are too many bugs and incompatibilities in browser implementations. So I am using newly introduced CSS Grid which seems more powerful and suitable for App layout.

Layout is: an App bar at top, together with a tab bar which lets you tab between multiple views - each one is a CSS Grid of its own - with flexible and fixed contents.

I cannot get inner elements to flex in height and get all the available space on the screen and not get cut off or fall outside viewport, thus the app should be contained in the vieweport with absolutely no scrolling/overflowing outside main screen.

How do I achieve this? How do you specify a row to fill available height of screen and no more?

JS Fiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/femski/5wpkvdo2/30/

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#root {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

element {
  --appbar-height: 6em;
}

element {
  --tabbar-height: 6em;
}

.maingrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 80% auto;
  grid-template-rows: var(--appbar-height) var(--tabbar-height) 80%;
}

.nav {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50%);
}

.mainTabrow {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 20%);
}

.maintab {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  align-items: start;
}

.detail {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr var(--tabbar-height) 33fr;
  background: grey;
}

.summary {
  grid-row: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.subtab {
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 33.333%);
}

.info {
  grid-row: 3;
  overflow: auto;
}

.detail_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="maingrid">
    <div class="nav">
      <h3>
        Search Bar
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Inside App bar
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="mainTabrow">
      <h3>
        Tab 1
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Tab 2
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Tab 3
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Tab 4
      </h3>
      <h3>
        Tab 5
      </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="maintab">
      <div class="detail">
        <div class="summary">
          <div>
            <h1>Flexible Summary Inside 1st Tab - we want this to be scrollable</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subtab">
          <h1>Subtab 1</h1>
          <h1>Subtab 2</h1>
          <h1>Subtab 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <div class="detail_grid">
            <div>
              <h1>
                Flexible scrollable Detail
              </h1>
            </div>
            <h1>
              We want this scrollable too
            </h1>
            <h1>
              Flexible scrollable Detail
            </h1>
            <h1>
              Flexible Detail
            </h1>
            <h1>
              Flexible Detail
            </h1>
            <h1>
              Flexible Detail
            </h1>
          </div>
          <h1>
            Flexible Detail
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Flexible Detail
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Flexible Detail
          </h1>
          <h1>
            Flexible Detail
          </h1>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You thought Flexbox was too buggy and inconsistent... so you moved to a *newer* module that was just implemented in browsers like a week ago? Riiight... :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *App should be contained in the viewport - absolutely no scrolling/overflowing outside main screen.*

Okay, so you have apparently defined the heights for the app and tab bars.

```
element {
  --appbar-height: 6em;
}
element {
  --tabbar-height: 6em;
}
```

With this information, you can use `calc()` to determine the height of the third element.

```
.maintab {
   height: (100vh - 12em);
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Now the layout will stay within the bounds of the viewport (i.e., no scrollbar on browser window).

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5wpkvdo2/31/)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

/* REMOVED FOR DEMO; not doing anything; heights added below
element {
  --appbar-height: 6em;
}

element {
  --tabbar-height: 6em;
}  */

.maingrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 80% auto;
  grid-template-rows: var(--appbar-height) var(--tabbar-height) 80%;
}

.nav {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  background: aqua; /* adjusted blue; easier to read text */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,50%);
  
  height: 6em; /* brought it from non-working code above */

}

.mainTabrow {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5,20%);
  
    height: 6em; /* brought it from non-working code above */

}

.maintab {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  align-items: start;
  
  height: calc(100vh - 12em); /* NEW */
  overflow: auto; /* NEW */
}

.detail {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr var(--tabbar-height) 33fr;
  background: grey;
}

.summary {
  grid-row: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

.subtab {
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,33.333%);
}

.info {
  grid-row: 3;
  overflow: auto;
}

.detail_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="maingrid">
        <div class="nav">
          <h3>
          Search Bar
          </h3>
          <h3>
          Inside App bar
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="mainTabrow">
                  <h3>
            Tab 1
          </h3>
          <h3>
          Tab 2
          </h3>
          <h3>
          Tab 3
          </h3>
          <h3>
          Tab 4
          </h3>
          <h3>
          Tab 5
          </h3>
        </div>

        <div class="maintab">
          <div class="detail">
            <div class="summary">
              <div>
                <h1>Flexible Summary Inside 1st Tab - we want this to be scrollable</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="subtab">
              <h1>Subtab 1</h1>
              <h1>Subtab 2</h1>
              <h1>Subtab 3</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="info">
              <div class="detail_grid">
                <div>
                  <h1>
                Flexible scrollable Detail
              </h1>
                </div>
                <h1>
                We want this scrollable too
              </h1>
                <h1>
                Flexible scrollable Detail
              </h1>
                <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>
                <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>
                <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>
              </div>
              <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>
              <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>
              <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>
              <h1>
                Flexible Detail
              </h1>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Taking a clue form your answer - I made small changes and now it renders perfectly in Chrome/Firefox and Safari Technology Preview (STP). Updated JSfiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/5wpkvdo2/35/ Unfortunately it does not work in iOS Safari yet - for that I have to hard-code pixel heights of "summary" and "detail_grid". This is unfortunate. I was expecting better form Apple. Anyhow CSS Grid is anyday better than Flexbox - fewer lines of code, lots of power and already better browser support !

Comment: Ah, yes. I figured you may want multiple scrollable areas in the `.maintab` section, but I wasn't entirely sure. So I just put one in there to illustrate the concept. I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks. Don't know why Apple claims support in iOS Safari 10.1 when its actually very buggy right now. Hopefully it will be better in next version.